# Codeigniter HMVC Re-Declare error coming

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI 2.0.2 and using 5.4 Modular extension..

I have user as a default controller.

```
class User extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
 } 

 public function login{ echo modules::run('login/main'); }
}
```

Here is my modules/login/controller

```
class Login extends MX_Controller{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

  $this->load->model('login_model','login');
 } 

  public function main{
     $arrUserInfo = $this->login->getUserInfo();
  }
}
```

If I use "MX_Controller" then I am getting below error
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI in **E:\Projects\mySite\application\third_party\MX\Base.php on line 55**

So I have change with "CI_Controller" then I am getting below error

**An Error Was Encountered**
Unable to locate the model you have specified: login_model

I am not getting why modular MVC not working.. If anyone have an idea then please share it.
thanks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After beating my head on the desk for a while and Googling around, I found the answer. Your `User` controller should extend `MX_Controller`, not `CI_Controller`:

```
class User extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    } 

    public function login { echo modules::run('login/main'); }
}
```

Apparently, any controller that you're calling a module controller from must extend `MX_Controller`, even if it is not itself part of a module.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Module::run` weithin a controller only in Views. Instead of that you have to use:

```
$this->load->module('folder/controller');
$this->controller->method();
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, please format your code appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, when loading models you must specify the module name.

i.e.  `$this->load->model('login/login_model','login');`